# How to get focused node in dijit.Tree?

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

Is there a simple method to retrieve which tree node has current focus/highlight in a dijit.Tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation for it, but the `lastFocused` property of the dijit.Tree instance can be used to obtain the node with the current focus.  If no item has the current focus, the value will be `null`.  The `_onNodeFocus` method of dijit/Tree.js indicates how the `lastFocused` property is used.